# Open-COBOL Uknown seg fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, cobol

I've been trying to teach myself COBOL. While attempting to do this i've run into an issue I can't figure out.

I'm running ubuntu 16.04, and using GnuCOBOL (Open-COBOL) to compile. I thought this may have been an issue with the Open-COBOL version from the repository so I have compiled from source, and receive the same issue.

When trying to run this code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. Multi.

DATA DIVISION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
*> Group Value
   01 VALS.
*> Elementary Value
      05 VAL-1 PIC 9(03) VALUE 4.
      05 VAL-2 PIC 9(03) VALUE 3.
      05 RESULT PIC 9(06).


PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MULTIPLY VAL-1 BY VAL-2 GIVING RESULT.
   DISPLAY "Result is =" RESULT.
   DISPLAY 'GROUP DATA ITEM = ' VALS.
```

I receive:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I compiled with:

```
cobc -free -o Multi.o ./Multi.cob
```

I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong, and what causes the seg fault. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What command are you using to run your program?

Comment: Just ./Multi.o , That should work according the the GnuCOBOL examples.

Comment: That will only work if you compile with `-x`. By default, GnuCOBOL compiles to modules (which you run with `cobcrun`), not to executables.

Comment: @EdwardH This is the correct answer, and you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 5):

From your comment, it looks like you've mistaken the module `Multi.o` as an executable. The way to run the program `Multi` from the module is `cobcrun Multi`.

Alternatively, you can create a normal executable using `cobc -x`.